# Прерывается цикл, если условие не выполняется

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал небольшую программку для интернет-магазина, которая берет значения названия товаров из XLS-таблицы, сравнивает их с CSV-табличкой и парсит наличие этих товаров в новую табличку.

Проблема в том, что названия товаров в CSV-табличке иногда редактируются и, если совпадения не найдено, цикл останавливается и наличие парсится до первого такого несовпадения. Если дописать условие(ниже приведено с ним), что при несовпадении просто добавлять к счетчику +1 и идти дальше, то наличие вообще перестает парситься.

```py
import string
import csv
import requests
import shutil
import urllib3
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = '20-07.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Ассортимент']


idx=0
def write_cells(ostatok):
    sheet['AH' + str(5 + idx)] = ostatok

CSV_URL = 'https://opt-baza.com/tovari.csv'

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)
    csv_content = download.content.decode('cp1251', errors='replace')
    spamreader = csv.reader(csv_content.splitlines(), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        name = sheet['C' + str(5 + idx)]
        if row[1] == name.value:
            write_cells(ostatok = row[4])
            idx+=1
        if row[1] != name.value:
            idx+=1

print("Успех")
wb.save(filename='20-07-NAL.xlsx')
```

Comment: Вместо `if row[1] == name.value:` и `if row[1] != name.value:` используйте `if row[1] == name.value: ... else: ...`. Вообще, `idx+=1` можно вытащить из `if`, т.к. оно у вас в любом случае должно выполняться, тогда останется один `if` без `else`.

Comment: Если из под `if` увести счетчик `idx+=1` и поставить его под циклом `for`, то парсится только 1-ая строка и всё. Если поставить `idx+=1` под `with`, то не парсится вообще ничего. Через `else: idx+=1` тоже ничего совсем не парсится.

Comment: Нужно под if но внутри цикла for оставить: https://pastebin.com/fFyg9qEB Это эквивалентно тому что у вас сейчас в коде написано, но более "красиво". По поводу того, почему не парсится - запустите под отладчиком или добавьте отладочный вывод строк и имен, тогда возможно будет понятнее. Без вашего excel файла невозможно проверить, что у вас в коде не так - может вы вообще не из тех ячеек данные читаете?

Comment: Если имена из CSV файла соответствуют именам в табличке xls, то парсер работает, но только в таком случае: https://pastebin.com/SAxgf6rd  . Как запустить отладчик? у меня Visual Code.

Comment: Добавьте в вопросе пример как у вас выглядят данные

Comment: `Как запустить отладчик? у меня Visual Code.` - поставить точку останова (красный кружок слева от номера строки), слева нажать на треугольник с жуком, нажать Run and Debug, в открывшемся меню выбрать Python File, отладчик остановится на точке останова. Слева в окошке Watch можно добавить отслеживаемые переменные или выражения. Сверху посредине будет панель управления выполнением.

Comment: Имена уникальны, нет повторяющихся?

Comment: нет повторяющихся. Допустим, база ошиблась и внесла обновление: вместо "Акустическая гитара" - "Классическая гитара". На этом мой код перестает работать. Пробовал и Else, и if, и elif, и счётчики переставлял местами. Единственное рабочее решение - вручную править табличку NAL.xls и приводить в соответствие CSV-хе. Но такие исправления далеко не редкость.

Comment: Я бы выбрал из excel таблицы все имена, какие есть, положил в словарь с указанием номера строки, где это имя встретилось. Дальше проходим по именам в csv, ищем имя в словаре, если есть - пишем значение в строку в excel.

Comment: Понял, ну до словарей я еще не дошел. Как дойду, попробую такой метод. Спасибо за содействие!)